# Can't execute remote command using PuTTY/ Plink over SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, batch-file, putty, plink

Currently I am trying to run bat files `call_putty.bat` and `call_plink.bat`, but it isn't excuting the input commands in `-m E:\CREATE_ONT.txt`

When I remove `-m E:\CREATE_ONT.txt`, the SSH session is established successfully .

Here is the script inside 2 files *.bat.

```
putty.exe -ssh -2 -P 1022 admin@192.168.1.10 -pw admin -m E:\CREATE_ONT.txt
```

and

```
plink.exe -ssh -2 -P 1022 admin@192.168.1.10 -pw admin -m E:\CREATE_ONT.txt
```

In the `CREAT_ONT.txt` file is the code run when I manually copy and paste it into SSH session.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Any error message? What's the `plink.exe` output? What's in PuTTY Event log?

Comment: Hi. The `plink.exe` output is the putty window flash out and nothing happen. I can't see PuTTY Event log cause it disappear very fast.

Comment: You have to run `plink.exe` from existing console window (typically `cmd.exe`). The PuTTY event log is in the PuTTY window title context menu.

Comment: Thank Martin. When i applied this code `plink.exe -ssh -2 -P 1022 admin@192.168.1.10 -pw admin -m E:\CREATE_ONT.txt` directly to `cmd.exe` the error came out `FATAL ERROR: Server refused to start a shell/command` . Any advise how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you do this? `plink.exe -ssh -2 -P 1022 admin@192.168.1.10 -pw admin < E:\CREATE_ONT.txt` What the output will be?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I do as you said and this is the ouput: `Started a shell/command;
Sent EOF message;
Disconnected: All channels closed`

Comment: OK and did it execute the command? Do you expect any output?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The command still won't execute. Nothing happen :(

Comment: And if you type the same commands on `plink.exe` console?

Comment: When i remove `< E:\CREATE_ONT.txt` the result of `plink.exe` is the SSH connection is established and the window console is won't disappear. I copy commands from file `CREATE_ONT.txt` and it run normaly.

Comment: Did you check server log? (when using the `< E:\CREATE_ONT.txt`)